# How to Pass or Transfer Image Background in Main Tabbar to another Tabbar Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, image

Today I have Questions
I want to know how to pass image from tabor first page to another tabbar.

Here My `Main.StoryBoard` :

[image]

If I pick an image from first tabbar:

[image]

I picked image from camera roll and image stored in Variable or Value
UIImageView name is -> BlurBackgroundImage

Here My code is first tabbar :

```
//UIImageView
@IBOutlet weak var BlurBackgroundImage: UIImageView!

//Code for Pass Image (I Watched from Youtube Tutorial)
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    
    let parsetoAnotherViews = segue.destinationViewController as! Schedule_FEED;
    parsetoAnotherViews.RecieveBackground = BlurBackgroundImage.image;
    
    
    let parsetoAnotherViews2 = segue.destinationViewController as! FEEDNOW_FEED;
    parsetoAnotherViews2.RecieveBackground = BlurBackgroundImage.image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it successful,I solved this problem with code in google and S.O.

Here My Code Enjoy!!!

```
//Another Tabbar
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let MainTabImageBG = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first as! MainPage_FEED;
    self.RecieveBackground = MainTabImageBG.BlurBackgroundImage.image;
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    BlurBackgroundImage.image = RecieveBackground;


}
```